# How to create a new record without executing a database query?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have `Question` and `Answer` models. The *Question hasMany Answers*. Following commands run in the `php artisan tinker` mode invoke a database query for no apparent reason:

```
$q = new Question;
$q->answers[] = new Answer; // invokes the below query

// the executed query
select * from `answers` where `answers`.`question_id` is null and `answers`.`question_id` is not null
```

As you see, **there is no need for database call whatsoever**. How can I prevent it?

Comment: Can you check whether `$q->answers()->save($answer)` runs a SELECT query given that $answer is already created?

Comment: @ThePurpleK Sorry, but I could not understand what you mean. The query is run because of the `$q->answers` usage, as was pointed out by Joel's answer below

Comment: I was assuming that your intention was to associate a new Answers record with a Question record. I was wondering whether the code I gave would prevent the unneeded database call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing that because you're assigning it to the `Question` object. It wants to see if you're adding an extant record reference. **All Laravel Eloquent models contain magic methods for properties**, and trying to use them as temporary data storage is a *really* bad idea unless you've defined a property on them ahead of time for that specific purpose.

Just use a regular array instead and then associate them after the models have been prepared.

Documentation on one-to-many relationships:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but I need to simulate the relationship. Is there any way to use the `$q->answers` as a temporary storage?

Comment: I've never had to do that so I can't say for certain. `$model->exists` is a public property for some reason. You can try mimicking properties (including the one-to-many relationship model) and forcing `exists` to `TRUE` to see if you can trick Laravel into not doing checks.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `$q->answers`, Laravel tries to load all of the answers on the question object - regardless of whether they exist or not.

Any time you access a relationship on a model instance, you can either call it like `answers()` and get a query builder back, or you can call it like `answers` without parentheses and Laravel will fetch a collection for you based on the relationship.

You can prevent it easily by doing this:

```
$q = new Question;
$a = new Answer;
```

And then, when you're ready to save them, associate them with each other. In its simplest form, that looks like this:

```
$q->save();
$q->answers()->save($answer);
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but I need to simulate the relationship. Is there any way to use the `$q->answers` as a temporary storage?